# How can I deal with compiler error c2660 in recursive function and iterative function?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
double recursive(int n);
double iterative(int n);
int n;
double ans1, ans2;

int main(int n) {
    do {
        printf("input:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        ans1 = recursive(n);
        ans2 = iterative(n);
        printf("%f", ans1);
        printf("%f", ans2);
    } while (n != 0);
    return 0;
}

double recursive(int n) {
    double result = 0.0;
    result += (1 / n);
    return recursive(n); 
}

double iterative(int n) {
    int i;
    double result = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result += (1 / n);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Visual studio says that recursive function and iterative function has c2660 error. I think I used one arguments each when declaring the function and using the function. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `int main(int n)` is not a valid signature for `main`

Comment: `recursive()` is an infinite loop

Comment: @UnholySheep It isn't one of the standard forms but it is a legal implementation defined form in C. Edit : though the immediate use of `scanf("%d", &n);` shows that this is probably not intended.

Comment: `recursive` does not make much sense. It has no base case (that is the terminating condition). It is always setting `result` to `0` prior to addition. You should look up for some recursion examples and/or theory

Comment: What is the text of the error? Don't expect everyone to look up error codes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's the _compiler_ which decides the valid implementation-defined forms of main(), not the programmer. That means if `int main(int)` compiles cleanly, the compiler must document what that form does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big issue here is in your `recursive` function.  Every recursive function needs a base case.  That is, there must be some condition that, when true, does not cause a recursive call.  Also, unless that condition is based on some global variable (which is not a good idea), you need to change the parameter(s) with which you call the function as otherwise it'll just do the same thing every time and never reach the base case.  As you have it, no call to `recursive` will ever return since it always ends up calling itself with the same argument.

Without understanding the purpose of the function, it's difficult to know what that condition should be.

Comment: And a recursive function should call itself with at least one different parameter which is part of the condition. Calling itself with unchanged parameters is most likely an endless recursion, regardless if there is a base case or not.

Comment: This is very true. But every recursive function also needs an update. Some way to converge toward the base condition. That may be a worthwhile addition to this answer.